# NODE and rewriting - Replace world alternatively in a text?

Tags: node.js, replace, rewriting

Good morning,

I would like to rewrite a text and replace words that are often repeated.

- Is it possible to replace a word by another word chosen at random from a list?
  ("women" by "girl or wife or female")
- Is it possible to replace a word but not every time? For example every 3 occurrences?

For the moment i use

```
srt = srt.replace(/women/gi, 'girl');
```

thanks

Comment: Yes, its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

My apologies. I thought this was Python by glancing at the code. Here is a Javascript version of the previous Python code.

For more info on using "indexOf" vs "includes" [check out this article](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-string-contains-substring-javascript/)

#### JavaScript

```js
const word_to_replace = "amazing";
const list_of_words = ["randWord1", "randWord2", "randWord3", "randWord4", "randWord5", "randWord6"];
let blob = "This is an amazing text blob where the word amazing is replaced by a random word from list_of_words. Isn't that amazing!";
let random_word;
let randint;

while (blob.indexOf(word_to_replace) !== -1) {
    randint = Math.floor(Math.random() * list_of_words.length);
    random_word = list_of_words[randint];
    blob = blob.replace(word_to_replace, random_word);
}
```

#### Python

```py
from random import randint


word_to_replace = "amazing"

list_of_words = ["randWord1", "randWord2",
                 "randWord3", "randWord4", "randWord5", "randWord6"]


blob = "This is an amazing text blob where the word amazing is replaced by a random word from list_of_words. Isn't that amazing!"

# Check if the word_to_replace is in the given blob.
# If there is an occurrence then loop again
# Keep looping until there aren't any more occurrences
while word_to_replace in blob:
    # Get a random word from the list called list_of_words
    random_word = list_of_words[randint(0, len(list_of_words)-1)]
    # Replace only one occurrence of word_to_replace (amazing).
    blob = blob.replace(word_to_replace, random_word, 1)

# Print the result
print(blob)
```

To do X amount of occurrences at a time change `blob.replace(word_to_replace, random_word, 1)` to `blob.replace(word_to_replace, random_word, 3)`. Note the number at the end. It means "how many occurrences at a time would you like to replace?"

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I'm sorry but is in python and i can't convert it to JS.
there is a problem with "from random import randint"

Comment: @gandolfi I've added a javascript version for you. My apologies, I didn't notice it was in Javascript.

Comment: No problem! If this question solved your problem please don't forget to mark it as accepted @gandolfi. Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

thanks to MsonC. i have converted python to JS

```
const word_to_replace = "amazing"

const list_of_words = ["randWord1", "randWord2", "randWord3", "randWord4", "randWord5", "randWord6"]


var blob = "This is an amazing text blob where the word amazing is replaced by a random word from list_of_words. Isn't that amazing!"

// Check if the word_to_replace is in the given blob./ If there is an occurrence then loop again // Keep looping until there aren't any more occurrences while (blob.includes(word_to_replace)) {
    // Get a random word from the list called list_of_words
    var random_word = list_of_words[Math.floor(Math.random() * (list_of_words.length))]
    // Replace only one occurrence of word_to_replace (amazing).
    blob = blob.replace(word_to_replace, random_word, 1) } // Print the result console.log(blob)
```